# Android: Execute methods when displaying components on screen without interacting with them

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder

I have started programming with FireMonkey on Android (until now I was programming in C++Builder 6), and the first problems begin to appear.

As an example:

In both BCB6 and FireMonkey on Windows, if I create a `TForm` with a `TPanel` that contains a `TProgressBar` inside of it, and in the `TForm.OnActivate` event I implement a method call that loops and displays the `TProgressBar` "advancing", it will executes perfectly. It shows the Form, the Panel, and the ProgressBar, and then executes the method.

If I implement the same "script" on Android, it executes the method during the "splash screen" before displaying the Panel with its components on the mobile screen, and displays them once the loop is finished. I have tried placing the call to the method in other events of the Form (`OnCreate`, `OnFocus...`, etc), but the result is the same.

In short, I don't know how to make it so that once the form with its components is displayed on the mobile screen, any algorithm begins to be executed, without the need to perform any type of interaction with them.

Is there a solution, or should I rethink my way of programming for Android?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use the Form's `OnShow` event instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the Form's `OnShow` event, try using [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) to delay executing the method until after the event handler exits, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      // method call here ...
    end
  );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Show event, it doesn't work either.
I have tried to test your solution but it cannot be implemented in c++, but it has given me the idea of working with threads.

I have created a thread class of the form:

```
    class TDowmload : public TThread
    {
       ....
    
    public:
    
         // User declarations
        __fastcall TDowmload(TComponent* Owner,bool CreateSuspended);
    };


__fastcall TDowmload::TDowmload(TComponent* Ownerint,bool CreateSuspended) : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
  Priority          = tpNormal;
  FreeOnTerminate   = true;
}

 
void __fastcall TDowmload::Execute()
{
   Synchronize(discharge);
   Terminate();
}

void __fastcall  TDowmload::discharge()
 {
   ..
   ..
   .. 
   // PhTemp  = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetTempPath();
   // One of the actions is to download an file :
   // ( PhTemp + "EjpFile.txt"))
   
 }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormActivate(TObject *Sender)
{

  Application->ProcessMessages();

  TDowmload *Hilo = new  TDowmload(this,false);

  PhTemp  = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetTempPath();
  while(!FileExists( PhTemp + "EjpFile.txt"))
   {
      Application->ProcessMessages();
      ......
      ......
   }
....
....

}
```

The thread works perfectly download the file but the components are not displayed on the screen until the end of the event code FormActivate (Also in OnCreate and Show events).